# Undeserved badge

Tags: support, badges

That's weird. I was just awarded a badge for the tag "binomial coefficients" even though I only have 88 total score in that category. It is some sort of software error?

**Update** Well, now my score has jumped up to 100. I don't know *what* is going on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1498960) of yours has the score of 12. But the question to which it was posted happened to be from an ongoing contest, and as a result, your answer was [temporarily deleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1498960/revisions). It was undeleted 14 hours ago.

After the undeletion, it took some time until the score-totaling and badge-issuing processes ran. To complicate this a bit further, your profile page is not generated anew every time it is viewed; the software will often serve a cached version of it. This makes it possible to receive a notification about a badge before having the change reflected on the profile page.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that I was seeing things.